# Can VC_redistx64 package be installed and used, without visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, redistributable, vcredist

I understand vc_redistributable is a set of libraries required to run applications built out of Visual studio. 
So at my work place, can I install vc_redist on a device and avail its benefits without installing visual studio on that device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is considered to be a preferred way to make the application running on other devices.

Can be downloaded from Microsoft site https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Alternate ways include statically linking, or distribute DLLs locally.

Note that the debug version is not distributed with `vc_redist`, generally you should not distribute the debug build of your software.